# [Flutter]'No module found' in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I'm currently facing an issue on Xcode : despite the fact that I've done some pod install I've always the same error : module '...' not found for every single module contained in the project.

[No module found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAgBX.png)

I've tested every solution that have been given on the internet but no results for me..

Thanks a lot for your help !

Edit : Here is the [flutter doctor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnubi.png).
Then when I run "flutter build iOS" here is [the error I've](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mAuv.png)

I only want to run it on a simulator at the moment so I don't think that error will helps us.

When opening the workspace after 'flutter clean', 'flutter pub get' and 'flutter build iOS' I've always the "no module found" error in Xcode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I was opening Xcode project from Project.xcodeproj instead of Project.xcworkspace.

1. First Please Use Flutter Doctor Command.
2. Flutter Clean.
3. Flutter pub get
4. Flutter Build ios.
5. Again open the Project in Xcode using Project.xcworkspace file.

I am sure it will helps you.

Comment: Dear Ajith,

I edited my post to show the results of your advices : do you think another advices can help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes sure please try with another devices if needs but most of this case this is the only solution will works